# Stored Procedures in entity framework returning columns from multiple tables

Tags: entity-framework-6, domain-model

I'm trying to understand what's the best way to integrate a stored procedure in EntityFramework 6.

I've created a stored procedure in sql server to make  a complex  query and I am only interested in 3 columns from that query. I could make it "match" the entire table and map it to a domain model class but feel like I am bringing more data than necessary. Should I bring all the columns in the domain model?

Other question is, where should I make the call to the stored procedure, in a repository? In the current project I have a ReportTemplateRepository but all methods there are returning a ReportTemplate, so adding a stored procedure call will return something different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into CQRS, i.e. **Command Query Responsibility Segregation**.  It says you should use different models for reading information (query) and writing information (command).  It seems to me that you are trying to use things 
things that are suited to commands (domain model/ repository) when what you are doing with this complex query is reading data.

So I suggest you create a class called say ReportProvider which is responsible for reading information from the database.  In it call your stored procedure and map the result to a new class that has the exact 3 properties that you need.